# MySQL handle unicode text for utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Tags: mysql, unicode, emoji

I am getting the following error when trying to insert a string to a table.

> Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x8D...' for column 'preview_text' at row 1

\xF0\x9F\x98\x8D is the smiling face emoji

As I understand from previous stackoverflow questions, I need to set the collation to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, but it was like that by default, and still.

[image]

What else should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after connection you should [define the charset](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset.html) like so:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';
```

Usually you will have an option in your client to set it (more elegant than a query), for example:
NodeJS:

```
mysql.createPool({
    ...
    charset : 'utf8mb4'
});
```

And PHP's MySQLi

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8mb4");
```